# Problem with preparing array with attendance for team

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I got Users, Absences and Reasons tables:

```
Users
id | name 

Absences
id | user_id:foreignKey | reason_id:foreignKey | deputy_id:foreignKey | start:date | end:date

Reasons
id | name
```

I got attendance calendar which looks like:

```
Day   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
-----------------------------------------------|
User1 | o | o | V | V | S | S | o | o | o | V  |
-----------------------------------------------|
User2 | T | o | o | o | H | V | o | V | o | V  |
-----------------------------------------------|
```

Where "V" is Vacation, "S" sick etc. I want to print each User attendance report in that table.

```
@foreach ($users as $user )
   <tr>
      <td> {{ $user->name }} </td>
   @if($user->absences != null)
      @foreach($days as $day)
         @foreach ($user->absences as $absence)
           @if($day >= $absence->start->format('d') && $day <= $absence->end->format('d'))
              // there check if $user->absence->reason_id == something ...
           @else
              
           @endif
         @endforeach
       @endforeach
    @endif
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Also I want to have a tooltip, where I print specific data for each day (reason name, deputy name).

I have no idea how to get the range between two dates in each absence, merge it to got f.e table of user absence days with another array with reason.:

```
[
  2 => ['reason_id => 1, deputy_id = 3], 
  3 => ['reason_id => 1, deputy_id = 3], 
  7 => ['reason_id => 2, deputy_id = 1]
]
```

Where keys [2,3,7] are the days of the absence.

Is there easier way to achieve that or should I rebuild the database structure?

Comment: For every absence you have start date and end date. You want to get days diff between this two dates? For that you can use Carbon. After using carbon you can easy say start->diff($end)->days. Is that what you need?

Comment: For example User defined 3 absences in specific month. I need to print those in table(column of User1) and color column checking the reason of absence. I assume I need an array of all absences days with array for each day with reason_id and deputy_id.

Comment: So you need
User1:
Absence 1 -> 22-01-2022 : Vacation |
Absence 2 -> 23-01-2022 : Vacation |
Absence 3 -> 29-01-2022 : Vacation

Comment: Something like this. I use Carbon->now()->daysInMonth, then I create array with days in specific month like $days = array ('1','2','3', [...], '28'); and in blade I iterate in user column for each value in the $days array. I don't have plan how to check if specific column is a Vacation or blank or Sick.

Comment: I think that you have bad approach overhere. I will replicate this now in laravel and post you an answer :)

Comment: Maybe should I store in Absence table, an array of integers which are number of days and itare through those absences and it's arrays?

Comment: I just posted an ansewer :)

Comment: @Aleksandar I've commented under your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my working solution :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Day</th>
        @foreach (App\Models\User::all() as $user)
            <th>{{ $user->name }}</th>
        @endforeach
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for ($i = 1; $i <= Carbon\Carbon::now()->daysInMonth; $i++ )
        <tr>
            <td> {{ $i }} </td>
            @foreach (App\Models\User::with('absence')->get() as $user)
                <td>
                    @foreach ( $user->absence as $absence )
                        @if ($i>= Carbon\Carbon::parse($absence->start)->day && $i<=Carbon\Carbon::parse($absence->end)->day)
                            <span>{{$absence->reason->symbol}} - {{ $absence->deputy->name }}</span>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
        @endfor
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also created repo for you so you can test this easy.

> https://github.com/djokicpn/vacation-calendar

1. git clone https://github.com/djokicpn/vacation-calendar vacation-project
2. npm install
3. composer install
4. php artisan key:generate
5. php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
6. php artisan serve

Results preview :
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks great, but unfortunately I don't have PHP 8.0 currently and I try to understand the solution including changing table orientation, where days are displayed in 1st row of <thead> and the usernames in the 1st column (like where you're presenting the days).

Comment: What larvel version are you running? I will update composer real quick

Comment: Laravel 8.83.0 . While I print days not as you in rows of 1st column but on thead, I got the problem, because there isn't spaces on days without absence

Comment: here you have version 8 https://github.com/djokicpn/vacation-calendar-v8 :) enjoy!

Comment: or you can give me your repo so i can review your code. i really dont mind @kalview

Comment: I'll prepare it and send you link

Comment: At the moment even if I declared relation between Reasons and Absence I can't access in view like you did : $absence->reason->symbol.

Comment: give me permission to push to your repo, i fixed your issue :) my user is djokicpn

Comment: I forked your project. Here is working solution : https://github.com/djokicpn/cal

Comment: You has been added :)

Comment: Thanks! You explain me a lot! Only got question how does the $user->cell work? From what it comes from?

Comment: you are the most welcom :)

Comment: I've edited my last question: how does the $user->cell work? From what it comes from?

Comment: I just used user's object to add variable "cell". that is why im doing that outside for loop.